# looping thought results in FBRequestConnection Swift

Tags: arrays, loops, swift, dictionary

I have hard coded the eventName, appended it my eventNameArray so I can assign it to a UILabel in my table view. This works fine.

```
func fetchInfo() {


    FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("FBpage/events?fields=name,is_date_only,cover,description", completionHandler: {(connection: FBRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) ->
    Void in

            var eventData = result["data"] as [NSDictionary]
            var getEvent = eventData[0]
            var eventName = getEvent.objectForKey("name") as String
            self.eventNameArray.append(eventName)

            self.tableView.reloadData()


    }
 as FBRequestHandler)


    }//end of fetchfunc
```

But actually eventData has more than one dictionary in it(It looks more like this but over and over again up to 10+ events)

```
cover =     {
    "cover_id" = 111;
    id = 11;
    "offset_x" = 0;
    "offset_y" = 0;
    source = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-    9/s720x720/1484689_43320_n.jpg?";
    };
description = "Description for 1st event";
id = 111;
"is_date_only" = 0;
name = "First Event";
"start_time" = "2015-04-11T21:00:00+0800";
}, {
cover =     {
    "cover_id" = 222;
    id = 222;
    "offset_x" = 0;
    "offset_y" = 63;
    source = "https://fbcd-xpa1/t3242_431.png";
};
description = "Description for 2nd event";
id = 22222;
"is_date_only" = 0;
name = "Second Event";
"start_time" = "2015-04-10T21:00:00+0800";
}
```

How would I loop though this so I could get all of the objectForKey("name") and append it to my eventNameArray instead of hard coding. I understand what I have got down now just not sure how to refactor this so I can grab everything

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With a loop:

```
var eventNames: [String] = []

for event in events as [[NSObject:AnyObject]] {
    let eventName = event["name"] as String
    eventNames.append(eventName)
}
```

or more swift like using closures:

```
let eventNames = (events as [[NSObject:AnyObject]]).map({$0["name"] as? String})
```

keep in mind that i am asuming that every event has got a name

If you want to make sure that you produce a crash you need can first check it the value exists.
loop:

```
var eventNames: [String] = []

for event in events as [[NSObject:AnyObject]] {
    if let eventName = event["name"] as? String {
        eventNames.append(eventName)
    }
}
```

closure:

```
let eventNames = (events as [[NSObject:AnyObject]]).map({$0["name"] as? String})
```